# Does the following computer science/optimization theorem have a proof?

Tags: derivatives, inequality, optimization, algorithms, computer-science

I have been reading about a theorem in math called the **"Schema Theorem"** - this theorem is one of the first theorems from the field of evolutionary computing and genetic algorithms, largely responsible for justifying the use of "genetic algorithms" to solve optimization problems when the derivative of the objective function is either unknown or not clearly defined.

"Genetic algorithms" can be used in many different types of optimization problems, such as finding the roots of a polynomial. For example, we could use the "genetic algorithm" to find the roots (the zeros) of the following polynomial (this polynomial will be referred to as the "objective function", i.e. the objective of the optimization/root finding):

f(x, y) = x sin(4x) + 1.1y sin(2y)

Essentially, the "genetic algorithm" would start by taking random values of "x" and "y" and record the corresponding value of "f(x,y)" for each random combination of "x" and "y" : the value of "f(x,y)" for a given combination of "x" and "y" is called the "fitness". The "genetic algorithm" works by taking many such random combinations of "x" and "y" and recording which combinations produce lower fitness values (i.e. which coordinates of "x" and "y" correspond to low elevation regions on the f(x,y) surface). The "genetic algorithm" then "combines" (i.e. "mutates") combinations of "x" and "y" that produced low fitness values, and re-evaluates "f(x,y)" at these new "mutated combinations" of "x" and "y". The "genetic algorithm" repeats this mutation process many times until it successive differences in "f(x,y)" are negligible, or after a predefined number of iterations - this is very useful in problems where evaluating the derivative of the objective function can be extremely time consuming or costly, or the derivative of the objective function is poorly defined (i.e. standard optimization algorithms like gradient descent and newton-raphson can not be performed). The optimization process for the "genetic algorithm" can be seen below:

[image]

An interesting observation about the "genetic algorithm" is that it does not "promise or guarantee" convergence to the true minimum point of the objective function during the optimization process. But what the "genetic algorithm" does guarantee, is that "the overall fitness of the objective function is guaranteed to improve as the number of iterations increase". In other words, the "genetic algorithm" will reach closer to the true minimum of the objective function after "m iterations" compared to "n iterations", where m >> n. This idea is expressed in one of the original and fundamental theorems of genetic algorithms, called the "Schema Theorem" (see below):

[image]

Apparently, this theorem states that "schemas" (e.g. combinations of "x" and "y") that produce better fitness values are more likely to "survive after mutation" - i.e. the expected number of "schemas" that produce better fitness values are likely to increase as the number of iterations increase.

**Question:** I have spent a long time trying to either find a derivation of proof of the Schema Theorem - something which attempts to mathematically explain why the "genetic algorithm" is guaranteed to move towards the true optimum of the objection function as the number of iterations increase (rhetorical question: after all, why does the "genetic algorithm" not result in worse fitness results?). After all:

[image]

**Why does this inequality hold?**

I am very curious to see if there is a mathematical proof that justifies one of the most important and earliest theorems in "genetic algorithms" and evolutionary computing - does anyone know if the Schema Theorem has a proof?

Thanks!

**Reference:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holland%27s_schema_theorem
- https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/2014/carrjk.pdf
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/schema-theorem (alternate statement of theorem)
  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51892214_The_Exact_Schema_Theorem/link/02bfe50f6181790d85000000/download
- http://dynamics.org/Altenberg/FILES/LeeSTPT.pdf
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/vignettes/GA.html

**Note: An Example of Optimization using the Genetic Algorithm in the R Programming Language**

[image]

```
library(GA)


  #define function to be optimized
Rastrigin <- function(x1, x2)
{
  20 + x1^2 + x2^2 - 10*(cos(2*pi*x1) + cos(2*pi*x2))
}

x1 <- x2 <- seq(-5.12, 5.12, by = 0.1)

#run optimization through the genetic algorithm (with constraints)
GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness =  function(x) -Rastrigin(x[1], x[2]),
         lower = c(-5.12, -5.12), upper = c(5.12, 5.12), 
         popSize = 50, maxiter = 1000, run = 100)


GA | iter = 1 | Mean = -37.396067 | Best =  -6.441093
GA | iter = 2 | Mean = -29.00421 | Best =  -2.51091
GA | iter = 3 | Mean = -22.89516 | Best =  -2.51091

....

GA | iter = 90 | Mean = -3.025916e+00 | Best = -9.301074e-06
GA | iter = 91 | Mean = -5.725962e+00 | Best = -9.301074e-06
GA | iter = 92 | Mean = -5.858303e+00 | Best = -9.301074e-06
....

GA | iter = 250 | Mean = -3.581667e+00 | Best = -1.103990e-06
GA | iter = 251 | Mean = -5.160585e+00 | Best = -1.103990e-06
GA | iter = 252 | Mean = -7.226593e+00 | Best = -1.103990e-06


summary(GA)

## Solution = 
##                x1           x2
## [1,] 5.722083e-05 9.223472e-05
```

[image]

Comment: In reference https://dynamics.org/Altenberg/FILES/LeeSTPT.pdf provided, it is shown that Theorem 3 (Schema Theorem, page 9) can be obtained as a corollery of Theorem 1 (Price's Theorem, page 6). But the inequality looks slightly different from that of Wikipedia. BTW I don't know enough stats to help.

Comment: There's a fairly straightforward exposition in [these lecture notes](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~sudhoff/ee630/Lecture03.pdf).

Comment: Hello! Thank you everyone for your comments! I have come across both of these links before - nfortunately,  none of these links contain proper proofs and derivations as to why this inequality holds. Thank you!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/148362/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4295279/14578, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/550801/2921, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/560288/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: The question was also asked on [Artificial Intelligence Stack Exchange](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/34153/2444). The best place to ask this question is indeed AI SE, as this is an AI or computational intelligence topic. So, I guess all other versions should be removed, IMHO.